# TaskJuggler failed produce

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I'm fill my org-mode file with Cyrillic tasks names, and when i try generate TaskJuggler export file i'm got error:

```
org-taskjuggler-compile: TaskJuggler failed with errors: Error: UTF-8 encoding 
error in line 11:   task __________ "<?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?> <?><?><?><?><?><?><?>
<?> <?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?><?>" {
```

Not sure so its related with TaskJuggler but i'f found this line in source code on github.

And second, from command line exported file *.tjp to html report going fine.
Maybe i must something configure in the SpaceEmacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting language environment variables in Emacs helped in my case:

```
(setenv "LC_ALL" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LANGUAGE" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_COLLATE" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_CTYPE" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_MESSAGES" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_MONETARY" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_NUMERIC" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_TIME" "en_US.UTF-8")
```

Check what locale settings you use in shell environment by running `locale` and set your emacs variables accordingly.

Comment: You might like to describe your case (in as much detail as possible).

Comment: Yes, it's work!

Comment: @Stefan I use spacemacs and just added this code in `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()` function in .spacemacs dot file.